# SUDS (SOAP) from the Python console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, soap

I´m trying to install a SOAP API called SUDS, on a Windows 7 OS, to be able to run SOAP from the QGIS Python console and pyQGIS/Python scripts.

The only Python I have installed is the one comming with QGIS 2.01 standalone. How can I install an external Python library like SUDS, to be used within QGIS Python scripts and console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not see the forrest for all the trees ....

Just add the library to the PYTHONPATH

http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could copy the package files to 
`%programfiles%\QGIS Dufour\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (change appropriately for your QGIS version). That way `PYTHONPATH` can stay unmodified, however updating to a newer version of QGIS may delete the package, plus you'd have to repeat this several times in case you wanted to use several, parallel QGIS installations.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your answer?